# How to display only the head of the columns froma csv file using Pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to parse a csv file and I need to display only the head so then I can parse the whole csv.

This is the first line of the csv

```
Name    Email   Financial Status    Paid at Fulfillment Status  Fulfilled at    Accepts Marketing   Currency    Subtotal    Shipping    Taxes   Total   Discount Code   Discount Amount Shipping Method Created at  Lineitem quantity   Lineitem name   Lineitem price  Lineitem compare at price   Lineitem sku    Lineitem requires shipping  Lineitem taxable    Lineitem fulfillment status Billing Name    Billing Street
```

The first line from all columns, but I'm getting this `#1001 #1002 #1003 #1004` that are the first strings of the first column, and only that.

So, here's the question, how can I print just the first row of each column and then parse each column?

here's the code that I've written

```
from googletrans import Translator
import csv
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("orders_export.csv")
data = df.head()
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):

    df.to_csv("file_name.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')

print (data)
```

the first 5 rows are like this

[image: This is the output Right now]

and it was meant to be this way 
[image: Expected Output]
 so then I can parse by column name

Comment: maybe include the first 5 rows of your csv file and also what you expect theoutput to be

Comment: I`m going to do this RN

Comment: `data = df.iloc[:0, :]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure i understand your question fully, but if you need the names of your pandas dataframe you can use `df.columns`, which will return a list of your column names.

If you want to access a column in your dataframe you use `df.loc['column name']`, which will return the column as a Series object.

For more info you might want to check the pandas [guide to indexing dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).